# 403 Forbidden when attempting to upload a video via the O365 Video REST API

Tags: office365

I am attempting to upload a video into my tenant's video portal via the O365 REST API, but am receiving the following error response:

> responseText: "{"error":{"code":"-2130575251,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted.
>   Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation
>   again."}}

Here is my code - note this is just to create the empty container before the actual video bits are uploaded.

```js
var ChannelId = '8fc68a0a-529c-4576-bd62-ab6505b2be3a';
var requestUrl = "/portals/hub/_api/VideoService/Channels('" + ChannelId + "')/Videos";
var requestHeaders = { 
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};
var requestBody = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Publishing.VideoItem' }, 
                    'Description': ' { This is a test video uploaded via the video portal REST API } ', 
                    'Title': ' { Test Video } ' 
                  };
                  
$.ajax({
 url: requestUrl,
 method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    headers: requestHeaders,
    contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 },
    error:function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I've tried to find a sample on dev.office.com and https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/video-rest-operations but haven't found anything for uploading a video. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this? Or were you able to upload the video because I too have the same requirement